# What is a Windows 95 "start" (not setup) CD?

Tags: windows-95

I have this CD here and it does not seem to be a normal setup CD because I cannot boot from it.

Also the text on the CD says "Go to Start > run and then enter d:startimw"

As you can see it is run like a normal program and it is not a setup disk to install Windows 95.

But what is its contents?

[image: Win95 Start cd]

Comment: You're correct that this isn't a Win95 install CD but for clarity no *official* Windows 95 install CD is bootable, they all require the use of a boot floppy. Booting from CDs was not a supported feature on PCs when Windows 95 was a current OS.

Comment: @mnem Good to know, didn't know that.

Comment: Easiest way to find out might have been to just run it and see…

Comment: Doesn't have a key written in Sharpie on it so no matter what's on it it's useless.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A machine translation of https://www.winhistory.de/more/win95plus.htm#start says that "The start! Series (one version for Windows 95 and one for Windows 98) is an interactive tutorial for how to use Windows".

Comment: Makes sense because Windows ME CD2 is also a tutorial.

Comment: I believe this was known as "Windows 95 Starts Here" in English.

Comment: @somega The page linked in pndc's answer mentions a weird synchronisation, but the sample given on the page sounds pretty normal to me. Could you maybe dump the iso and upload it somewhere?

Comment: @Dakkaron I cannot upload it because it's copyrighted. On the website there is a Swiss woman speaking and that is why it sounds funny to Germans. But the language is 100% correct. Maybe if I find the time I can tell you if on my CD the audio is the same.

Comment: @Dakkaron I checked it and the voice is the same.